# In general, for an $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, how many linearly independent eigenvectors can a single eigenvalue have?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Studying Jordan canonical form.

Say J is the Jordan form of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$.

1)
I understand that if in the Jordan matrix, an eigenvalue appears in a single Jordan block of size greater than 1 (meaning it has algebraic multiplicity greater than geometric multiplicity) then essentially in order for A to have a complete set of n linearly independent eigenvectors, then we’d need the other at most n-2  possibly non distinct eigenvalues contribute n-1 linearly independent eigenvectors.

2)
The notes then say that if a matrix has such an eigenvalue then it can’t have a complete set of n linearly independent eigenvectors.

From this, I currently want to deduce that a single eigenvalue has(can contribute) at exactly one eigenvalue?

In general, for an $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, how many linearly independent eigenvectors can a single eigenvalue have?

Comment: Consider the identity matrix with an eigenvalue of $1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How many linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ does the zero matrix have?

Comment: As many as the basis for the vector space we’re considering? But if we have such an eigenvalue, this means it must have algebraic multiplicity n right?

Comment: Certainly, since geometric multiplicity is less than or equal to algebraic multiplicity.